# How can I redirect requests to a subdomain based on their path with Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

For example, I'd like to redirect http://my-site.com/blog/post1 to http://blog.my-site.com/post1. I've tried to find an answer elsewhere but it is always going in the opposite direction (redirecting from subdomain to a path).

If possible, I'd like to do this purely with S3 so we don't have to setup a load balancer or proxy server. In our case, https://my-site.com will be deployed with S3 static website hosting behind a Cloudfront distribution. Is there a way to configure S3's redirect rules to redirect requests to a subdomain based on their path?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're redirecting to a subdomain doesn't really matter, and "based on their path" is pretty much how redirect routing rules in S3 work.

```xml
<RoutingRules>
  <!-- example.com/blog -->
  <RoutingRule>
      <Condition>
          <!-- no / goes here -->
          <KeyEquals>blog</KeyEquals>
      </Condition>
      <Redirect>
          <ReplaceKeyWith/> <!-- nothing -->
          <Protocol>http</Protocol>
          <HostName>blog.example.com</HostName>
      </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
  <!-- example.com/blog/* -->
  <RoutingRule>
      <Condition>
          <!-- note the / is after, not before, blog -->
          <KeyPrefixEquals>blog/</KeyPrefixEquals>
      </Condition>
      <Redirect>
          <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith/> <!-- nothing -->
          <Protocol>http</Protocol>
          <HostName>blog.example.com</HostName>
      </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax